# Probability of failure event?

Tags: probability

I have a very specific work-related question which I would like a second opinion on.

We have a device that can be powered via battery and AC mains. We have identified a specific failure mode where suddenly, the battery cannot provide power to the device. Let's call this event P(F).

In order to pose a risk to the user, the user must have the device "ON", in a particular state and obviously power the device via the battery. Let's call these events P(ON), P(STATE) and P(BAT).

We have identified approximately 10 failures where the battery cannot provide power to the device and we have sold 10,000 units. Keep in mind, that failure can only occur if the device is powered via the battery.

So what is the probability of a risk occurring to the user?

Is it;

1. P(ON) * P(STATE) * P(BAT) * P(F)
2. P(ON) * P(STATE) * P(F)
3. P(STATE) * P(F)

Any insight into this problem will be appreciated, I have been going round in circles for this issue.

thanks!

Comment: You could try answering this theoretically, but you would have to make quite a few assumptions about the process, which might not be true. If you have data it would help if you did some analyses/plots to check if there are any patterns.

Comment: What sort of assumptions were you thinking of?

Comment: That these events are all independent, which is what you are assuming when you are multiplying the probabilities.

Comment: That seems too simplistic. Surely, there is a more complex underlying process. E.g. being for a long time on battery will lead to failure (i.e. the battery runs out - you probably even have a pretty good idea how long the battery should last, so it might be almost more about modeling how often the battery will be needed for how long - plus possibly that the battery might degrade over time or something like that). If you have the necessary data from a relevant population, you could fit a multi-state model, where how long you are in a specific state could affect transition properties.

Comment: The notation in this post is confusing, because it conflates events with their probabilities.  As far as answering it goes, wouldn't you want to consider *at a minimum* the amounts of time each of the devices has been in service?  You also would want to be clearer about what these events are, especially concerning the relevant time frames (one use? one year? lifetime? something else?).